# How to calculate digits of Trott Constants?

Tags: numerical-value, integer-sequence

How to calculate digits of numbers ([Trott Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrottConstant.html)) whose continued fraction representation  is the same as the digits of its radix representation with *Mathematica*?

Comment: "However, attempts to extend the number of digits have proved problematic." (from the Mathworld article)

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.3888/tmj.10.2-2).

Answer (score 3):

```
WolframAlpha["trott constant", {{"ContinuedFraction", 1}, "Input"}, 
 PodStates -> {"ContinuedFraction__Fraction form"}]

(*
  HoldComplete[
    ContinuedFraction[
      0.108410151223111361511290811406415091122158090939091, 23
    ]
   ]
*)
```

You can sub in other numbers for the above 23

```
ContinuedFraction[0.108410151223111361511290811406415091122158090939091, 20]

(*{0, 9, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 17}*)
```